# ActiveAdmin - Pass locals to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activeadmin

In my `photos.rb` file I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
  form :partial => 'admin/forms/photo', :locals => { :events => Event.all }
end
```

In my `_photo.html.erb` file I want to be able to access the value of events, but it doesn't seem to be detectable.  How can I do this?

As requested in a comment, here is my form:

```
<% if events.any? %>
  <%= form_for [:admin, @photo], :validate => true do |f| %>
    <!-- insert a bunch of standard field divs here -->
    <div class="actions" style="margin-top: 20px">
      <% if @photo.new_record? %>
        <%= f.submit 'Create photo' %>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.submit 'Update photo' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <div style="font-size: 14px">
    You cannot add photos until you have added at least one event.
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error message I am getting is around the `events.any?` line:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 108ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `events' for #<#<Class:0x007fdb8e841b80>:0x007fdb8a93e7a8>)
```

Comment: can you post your partial too?

Comment: Do you have errors in browser or console when trying to access this form? cause I see you are passing the variables in the right way. If you have any errors in logs please attach them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another thought on this, if you want to check only if there are any Events in db you can make `any` call directly on `Class`:

```
<% if Event.any? %>
  do this
<% else %>
  do that
<% end %>
```

without sending variables to partial, the above code result in:

```
2.0.0p0 :004 > Event.any?
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events"
 => true
```

and leave the ActiveAdmin partial without locals:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
  form :partial => 'admin/forms/photo'
end
```

Comment: It feels a little messy though - I don't like to put logic in my template like that.  I'll check my error log later today and get back to you on that note.

Comment: Try this:  `form(:partial => 'admin/forms/photo',  :locals => { :events => Event.all })`

Comment: The parentheses didn't seem to help

Comment: `form(render :partial => 'admin/forms/photo', :locals => { :events => Event.all }) ` try out this one, it's strange when rails api says it should work but it didn't.

Comment: I got `undefined method `render' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x007fdb8ef1d5a8>`

Comment: Well, here I quit :-) there is not so much documentation to ActiveAdmin to pull this out, even if I used ActiveAdmin a lot of times, this one is over me. Sorry.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help.  I think I'll just go with your current solution as an slightly unfortunate workaround, because it works and it's only a little bit of logic in the view.  ActiveAdmin still has a long way to go I guess...

Answer (score 3):

```
form do |f|
  f.render partial: 'admin/forms/photo', locals: { f: f, events: Event.all }
end
```

Note that you will need to remove `form_for`, `semantic_form_for`, `active_admin_form_for` etc from your partial, since it will be covered by the `form do` part in the `admin/photos.rb`, otherwise there will be two nested forms.

Example partial:

```
# app/views/admin/forms/_photo.html.arb
if events.any?
  f.inputs do
    f.input :title, label: 'Etc'
    f.input :file
  end
  f.actions
else
  f.div 'You cannot add photos until you have added at least one event.', 
        style: 'font-size: 14px'
end
```

Comment: I tried this approach and the inputs in partial are rendered twice

Comment: @Stpn yeah, whenever I work with Active Admin I struggle with that kind of problems too, due to crazy Arbre context issues. Sometimes the inputs even end up outside the form :) Try using different approaches inside the partial, e.g. just `input` instead of `f.input` or vice versa. Also if you are using something like `=f.input`, remove `=` as Arbre outputs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
form do |f|
    render partial: 'admin/forms/photo', locals: { value: 'random_data' }
end
```

You can use **f.render** or just **render**.

**Note that `partial:` is required to send locals to the form**

**Example Partial**

```
#app/views/admin/forms/_photo.html.arb
active_admin_form_for [:admin, resource] do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs do
       f.input :name
       f.input :random if (value == 'random_data')
    end
   f.actions
end
```